# comparing and correcting multiple effects across many conditions

Tags: hypothesis-testing

say I have n response variables Y_in that I want to test with the same set of X_ij variables

I fit a model for each one

```
Y_i1 ~ B * Xij

... 

Y_in ~ B * Xij
```

So lets say I have three betas in each model

```
Y_i1 ~ B1 + B2 * Xij + B3 * Xij 

... 

Y_in ~ B1 + B2 * Xij + B3 * Xij
```

I want to find the list of significant effects among all my models, for example a list such as

B2 is significant in these conditions Ym .. Yn

B3 is significant in conditions Yp ... Yq

I need to do some kind of test correction here but I'm not sure how to apply it. Please advise how you might do this comparison.